# Visual Studio Code - How to show user snippets on top of other suggestions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have created a JavaScript 'user snippet' in the Visual Studio Code to make it slightly faster to call the `console.log()` method (a line of code that I write very frequently).

```
"Console Log": {
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
        "console.log($0);"
    ],
    "description": "JavaScript Console.log()"
}
```

The user snippet works, but when I type `log` into the editor, my custom snippet is at the bottom of the list.

[image: 'log' is at the bottom of the list]

Is there any way I can make this the first suggestion, rather than the last?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try setting:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily target user snippets - for example, I still have the VSCode default "log" snippet coming first before mine